# Unable to get result of productByHandle query when nil when using shopify_api with graphql query

Tags: ruby, graphql, shopify, shopify-api

I am trying to retrieve the result from a graphQL query when the product is nil by using the productByHandle query, but it's erroring out.

My code in Ruby:

```
client = ShopifyAPI::GraphQL.client
 product_handle_query = client.parse <<-'GRAPHQL'
  query ($productHandle: String!) {
   productByHandle(handle: $productHandle) {
     id
     handle
     title
     tags
     productType
     vendor
   }
 }
 GRAPHQL
result = client.query(product_handle_query, variables: {productHandle: productHandle})
puts result.data.productByHandle
```

This should return nil, but when I try and message out, it returns with this error:

NoMethodError (undefined method `productByHandle' for #< productByHandle=nil>)

This query works fine in Insomnia, where the output looks like this:

```
{
"data": {
"productByHandle": null
},
"extensions": {
"cost": {
"requestedQueryCost": 1,
"actualQueryCost": 1,
"throttleStatus": {
"maximumAvailable": 2000.0,
"currentlyAvailable": 1999,
"restoreRate": 100.0
}
}
}
}
```

I have also tried changing from String! (which is not-null type which is what is returning) to String, but I get this error:
GraphQL::Client::ValidationError (Nullability mismatch on variable $productHandle and argument handle (String / String!))
My variable for $productHandle is indeed a string, so not sure why this isn't working either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What does it mean to ask for a product and providing nil? Just curious for a use case.

Comment: I am querying for the product based on the product handle and it is returning nil because the product doesn't exist yet. @DavidLazar

Comment: How can you have a handle to something that does not exist? If you don't have a handle, why would you ask if nothing exists? Existential!

Comment: That is the point of this query, to see if the product exists before creating one. I don't want duplicate products in my store. @DavidLazar

Comment: The easiest way would be to handleize the title you wish to use, and then use that as your handle to call. You'd get back a product if it already exists, otherwise nil. But of course you can do it other ways. Not sure that matters.

Comment: Yep! That is what I'm going with. I was able to figure out my issue as well, thank you! @DavidLazar

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to read the result from the output above:

```
result.original_hash["data"]["productByHandle"]
```

This returns nil and allows me to continue to create a new product.